# Traditional IRA and SEP IRA at the same time

Tags: ira, retirement, sep-ira

I am self employed through my LLC and I am also employed by a company via W2

What would be my contribution limits to SEP IRA and Traditional IRA?

Are my SEP IRA contribution limits separate from my Traditional IRA ones?

Answer (score 0):

I called vanguard today and they said they were indeed separate. The harder question is more about whether you qualify for the SEP IRAs. Which they were unsure of, all right least not willing to go on the record talking about. They said I should contact a tax professional.

Comment: They're right. Their job is to know their products, not the details of your finances. Once you have enough money invested with them they may offer to cook you up with one of their advisors, but always remember that a service you are aren't paying for is going to be biased in favor of whoever is paying.